# Vue-router keeps appending # to existing routes. P.S this isn't the typical hash, history mode issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Using Vue 3, i have my router file set up this way

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";


const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: "/Portfolio",
        name: "Portfolio",
        component: () =>
            import(/*webpackChunkName: "DestinationDetails" */ "../views/Portfolio"),
    },
    {
        path: "/Services",
        name: "Services",
        component: () =>
            import(/*webpackChunkName: "DestinationDetails" */ "../views/Services"),
    },

    {
        path: "/details/:id",
        name: "PortfolioDetails",
        component: () =>
            import(
                /*webpackChunkName: "DestinationDetails" */ "../views/PortfolioDetails"
            ),
    },
    {
        path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
        redirect: "/Home",
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

I am also running a v-for loop to get paths from an API "https://api.fake.rest/ca2a6662-22d0-4010-ba08-0440ffe813ab/menu". 3 of the 5 url paths have a value of "#". the remaining two have normal paths.

```
<div
                    v-for="(men, index) in webMenu.menu_items"
                    :key="index"  class=" mt-32"
                >
                    <!-- <SidebarLink class="w-full" :to="{path:men.url}" icon="fas fa-home">{{
                        men.name
                    }}</SidebarLink> -->

                    <router-link class="w-full" :to="men.url"> {{men.name}} </router-link>
                </div>

                <p class="font-bold">{{webMenu.menu_text}}</p>
            </div>
```

Problem is now when the webpage loads initially, it works fine but after clicking on the portfolio or services link, the paths to the others are changed.

e.g if i was on the portfolio page and tried switching back to the home page, it would change the route path to "portfolio#" and refuse to switch pages.

Can anyone help explain why this is and a possible way to resolve it?

Comment: are you using @click.stop or event.propagation by any chance?

Comment: @Rippyblogger https://api.fake.rest/ca2a6662-22d0-4010-ba08-0440ffe813ab/menu the API which you are using for menus the URL path for home, about, and contact is not correct. There is just a # in the path, hence the weird behavior.

Comment: @Rahul no i am not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar issue.

For me the issue was that I was redirecting to new page using `router.push()` on click of a div.

And I was using `@click.stop = "myFunction"` . This was adding a  `#` in the url and not redirecting the user.

I tried different variation of this as well. I tried using `event` object as well like `event.stopPropagation()`. With this as well got same result.

**When I used `@click.prevent`, this everything worked as expected.**

PS:

You can use `catch` block to trace the error as well.

```
this.$router..push({
        name: "PAthName",
        params: { id },
        query: { id }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("Errors", e);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Should have updated this earlier.

The fix was relatively simple, all i did was change the binding from

```
<router-link class="w-full" :to="men.url"> {{men.name}} </router-link>
```

to

```
<router-link class="w-full" :to="`/${men.url}`"> {{men.name}} </router-link>
```

and voila!

Comment: Using route name would save you this trouble ;) Plus it gives you the flexibility to  change URL without updating all the links.